# DAX Rank Items Ignoring Sub-Categories

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Working in PowerBI, I have a dataset that can be split among a bunch of different dimensions. At the end of the day I want to create some bar chart visualizations that show the top X items along with an additionally generated item that will show the total of all items outside of the top X. I've got this all working fine. The roadblock I run into is when I add a second dimension into my visualization (i.e. as a legend item in a stacked bar graph). This causes my Rank measure to rank according to Dimension 1 and Dimension 2, when I only care about the overall rank according to Dimension 1.

**How do I create a rank measure to work on a single dimension when multiple dimensions are present?**

**Example**

Raw data in table named Fact:

[image: Raw Data in table Fact]

My measure to calculate the total amount:

```
Total Amount = SUM('Fact'[Amount])
```

My measure to calculate the company rank:

```
Company_Rank = 
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE('Companies Other'[Company]) = "Other"
    , [TopX_Selected] + 1
    , RANKX(
        ALL('Companies Other')
        , [Total Amount]
        ,
        , DESC
        , Dense
    )
)
```

My measure to aggregate the items outside of the Top X into Other:

```
TopX_Amount = 
// If within the Top X, return the value
IF([Company_Rank] <= [TopX_Selected]
    , [Total Amount]
    // Otherwise sum everything outside of the top X to include in Other
    , IF(
        SELECTEDVALUE('Companies Other'[Company]) = "Other"
            , SUMX(FILTER(ALL('Companies Other'[Company]), [Company_Rank] > [TopX_Selected]),  [Total Amount])
            , 0
    )
)
```

If I choose to display the top 3 companies (i.e. `[TopX Selected] = 3`) then everything is great:

[image: Top 3 Companies]

If I try to add Country to the legend of the visualization then everything goes off the rails because now the ranking is based on each Company/Country combination:

[image: Top 3 Company/Country Combinations]

What I want to see is similar to what I'd get when using the Top N filter on the visualization, but with the addition of the Other column:

[image: Top N Companies Visualization Filter]

I tried making `Company_Rank` a calculated column in `'Companies Other'`, but that doesn't seem like the *"right way"* to do it and I don't think that will update properly when users change the selected period.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and tribulation, I figured out a solution. Not surprisingly, it comes down to Row and Filter context which makes my head hurt and I still don't fully understand. That being said, after some debugging (using `CONCATENATEX` instead of `RANKX` to peak behind the scenes) it seems like the row context was fine, but the filter context was applying the Country filter no matter what I did (like trying to use `SUMMARIZE` or `CALCULATETABLE`). The solution is to remove the filter context for the fields that you don't care about, which in this case is `'Fact'[Country]`. So instead of basing the rank just on `[Total Amount]` it needs to be calculated as `CALCULATE([Total Amount], ALL('Fact'[Country]))`.

```
Company_Rank = 
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE('Companies Other'[Company]) = "Other"
    , [TopX_Selected] + 1
    , RANKX(
        ALL('Companies Other')
        , CALCULATE([Total Amount], ALL('Fact'[Country]))
        ,
        , DESC
        , Dense
    )
)
```

Voila, the updated table and chart:

[image: Updated Table and Chart]

Ideally this would be more generic so I wouldn't have to specify all of the fields I don't care about (i.e. *`[Country]`*) and I would only need to specify the fields I do care about (i.e. *`[Company]`*). I had hopes that `ALLEXCEPT` would be that holy grail, but I haven't gotten that to work yet.